# can we build the cordova android application with django as backend and Mysql as database

Tags: django, cordova, backend

I am trying to build the cordova application by using django as backend but I do not know how to do that
if anyone have been working on that please guide me

to build the cordova applcation with the django as backend
if anyone having solution that how I can connect the django default server to my cordova app

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to make requests from Cordova frontend to Django backend is to to set up a REST like API (HTTP requests via endpoint URLs that handle and produce JSON data) in Django backend. [Django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is one such helpful tool/library for this purpose.

You can then access these endpoints (URLs) from your Cordova frontend.

Here is an example how you would access the API endpoints:

```
fetch('https://your-django-backend.com/api/endpoint', {
  method: 'GET', // or 'POST', 'PUT', etc.
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    // Add any necessary headers here
  },
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Handle the data received from the backend
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle errors
  });
```

Comment: ya right I done that but my cordova app is not getting connected to my django local server  (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) can you please guide me with that

Comment: do you have any error message?

Comment: This will also need some cors setup

Comment: yes can please show me the setup for corsheaders